# pasting scraped data from web to new worksheet and name the worksheet based on values in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I'm a novice in VBA, was looking to export tables from HTML & I have been successful in that.

My code will create a new worksheet to paste the tables from each URL. Currently the new worksheet is named in a sequence of 1,2,3... I want help to rewrite this part of the code.

I have two columns and multiple rows, 1st column is for the URL from where the data needs to be copied and the 2nd column contains worksheet name.

Example:

Column 1 :
URL;http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-series/2489/england-tour-of-india-2016-17/matches

Column 2:
Eng-India

When the data is copied from column 1, I would like the code to name the new worksheet based on the values in column 2

Currently I use the below code:

```
Sub adds()
 For x = 1 To 2

 Worksheets("MATCH").Select
 Worksheets("MATCH").Activate
 mystr = "URL;http://www.cricbuzz.com/cricket-series/2489/england-tour-of-india-2016-17/matches"
 mystr = Cells(x, 1)
 Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = x
 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=mystr, Destination:=Range("$A$1"))
 'CommandType = 0
 .Name = "01000_1"
 .FieldNames = True
 .RowNumbers = False
 .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
 .PreserveFormatting = True
 .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
 .BackgroundQuery = True
 .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
 .SavePassword = False
 .SaveData = True
 .AdjustColumnWidth = True
 .RefreshPeriod = 0
 .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
 .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
 .WebTables = "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10" 
 .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
 .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
 .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
 .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
 .WebDisableRedirections = False
 .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
 End With
 Next x
 End Sub
```

Comment: You are assigning the values to `mystr` variable twice.

Comment: i think that the url is a test string, and will not be used in production code. the two assignments are backward though.